# Castle Windsor - List of complex types as parameters to component in xml

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have a component in my xml config file that takes an array of menu items. This works fine, each menu item is properly populated with its values.

One of its values, chart, is a complex type which itself contains two strings and a list of complex types. The list in chart is not populated properly and always contains one element who's properties are all set to their default values.

Here's the parameters section of my xml file:

```
<menuItems>
      <array>
          <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <chart>
              <title>Chart Title</title>
              <series>
                  <list>
                     <item>
                      <id>1</id>
                      <name>Series Title</name>
                     </item>
                  </list>
              </series>
            </chart>
          </item>
     </array>
</menuItems>
```

And my relevant classes:

```
[Convertible]
public class QueryMenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Chart Chart { get; set; }
}

[Convertible]
public class Chart
{
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public IList<ChartSeries> Series { get; set; }
}

[Convertible]
public class ChartSeries
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get Castle Windsor to properly populate the list of series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For folks that still looking for solution... I've removed  node for Series and it's work (checked for 3.2.0.0):

```
<menuItems>
  <array>
    <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <chart>
        <title>Chart Title</title>
        <Series>
          <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>Series Title</name>
          </item>
          <item>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>Series Title2</name>
          </item>
        </Series>
      </chart>
    </item>
  </array>
</menuItems>
```

Tech note: it seems that when it parsing <Series> it already knew that it is generic list, so called *GenericListConverter.PerformConversion* with <Series> as configuration node. And *PerformConversion* is calling *ListHelper<T>.ConvertConfigurationToCollection* and pass list of child nodes in tree.

So in case when we wrap items in <list> it's handled as collection with single item "list" (and there is no direct child nodes with values for id and name, so default is used).

In case if we are omitting <list> node, than *ListHelper<T>.ConvertConfigurationToCollection* receive 2 child nodes - "items" that parsed correctly.

[Sources of castle](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor).

And link to [GenericListConverter.cs](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/SubSystems/Conversion/GenericListConverter.cs).